# I am login as SuperAdmin but not getting any options for Bug Tracking System dropdown options

Tags: reportportal

I am login as 'Superadmin' but when I am clicking on 'Bug tracking system' dropdown, I am not getting the 'Jira' option. Is there any extra setting is required on 'ReportPortal' or 'Jira' side?

Answer (score 0):

That means that microservice, related to JIRA integration is not deployed.

Add `jira` section into you `docker-compose.yml` like here:

https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L147

or select it with in UI wizard at:

1. http://reportportal.io/download
2. configure file
3. Integration with BTS
4. Check JIRA
5. Generate file

[image]

[image]